# What is wrong in my JDBC insert/update command

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

This is about a simple booking/reservation table: key is anId for a timeOfBooking and dateOfBooking.

But when I try to do: insert if-not-exist, update if-exist, about a identifier linked to a time with this code:

```
declare anId varchar[18];
declare aDate;
declare aTimeStamp;
set @anId =?;
set @aDate=?;
set @aTimeStamp=?;
if (exists (select * from Booking as t  where t.AnId = @anId ))
begin update Booking set Date = @aDate and Time = @aTimeStamp  where AnId= @anId end
else begin insert into Booking (AnId, Date, Time) values(@anId , @aDate, @aTimeStamp) end ;
```

I end up with the jdbc layer returning this error :

```
'varchar' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put @ for variable names

```
declare @anId varchar(18);
declare @aDate datetime;
declare @aTimeStamp datetime;
```

Comment: The type must also be supplied, I think?

Comment: Correct Rory! I quickly copy and paste :)